# OpenSolaris Brandz and JNI a good mix?

Tags: java-native-interface, opensolaris

I'd like to run a java application on a OpenSolaris machine but this application uses a dll/so that I only have the linux binary. Can it be possible, and this is because I know nothing about the OpenSolaris Brandz feature, that I can deploy the dll on a linux brandz and link to it from a jvm running on the OpenSolaris side?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot mix Solaris and Linux binaries. What you might do is running the whole on the Linux branded zone.